# Différence entre « à part » et « autre que »

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre « à part » et « autre que » ?

Je n'ai aucun contexte parce que je pense que les deux sont tout à fait interchangeables. Est-ce que c'est vrai ?

Answer (score 6):

Les contextes usuels d'utilisation :

> *À part* : dans un endroit particulier, dans une autre place -  « Occuper une place *à part* (à l'écart). »

Il y a une notion d'un lieu différent de celui du groupe, de séparation d'un ensemble.

> *Autre que* : ce n'est pas celui-là, c'en est un autre -  « *Tout autre* que lui sera admis, s'il rempli les conditions. »

Il y a une notion de différence, de personnes ou d'objets extérieurs à un groupe ou à une entité.

---

*Complément suite au commentaire de Stéphane*

> « Les fruits, *à part/autres que/hormis* les pommes, … »

Dans ce contexte, les trois expressions sont équivalentes.

> - « Les fruits, hormis les pommes, … »
> - « Les fruits, à part les pommes, … »

... sont interchangeables .

> - « Les fruits, *mises* à part les pommes, … »

L'ajout de l'adjectif *mises* est souvent utilisé pour insister sur la particularité des pommes en question.

> - « Les fruits, autres que les pommes, … »

Le *r* de *autres* suivi de la consonne du mot *que*, qui empêche l’allitération, rend la prononciation correcte difficile.

Comment: Tu rates complètement l'intérêt de la question. Dans ton exemple *autre que* n'est pas la locution à laquelle la question s'intéresse. Voilà un exemple: « Les fruits, *à part* (ou *autres que*, *hormis*) les pommes, … »

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of « à part », « autre(s) que » (and « hormis ») are essentially all the same, but unlike « à part » and « hormis », « autre(s) que » is rarely, if ever used to BEGIN a sentence, as [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=autre%20que%2CAutre%20que%2Chormis%2CHormis%2CA%20part%2Ca%20part%2Cautre%20que%20Autre%20que%2CAutres%20que%2Cautres%20que&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cautre%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAutre%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chormis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHormis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAutres%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cautres%20que%3B%2Cc0) shows.

I believe that the reason behind the curious results of this Ngram comes from the comparative and modifying nature of the word « autre(s) », and that identifying an exception by « autre(s) que » BEFORE the initial reference to the whole group from which the exception comes sounds awkward and out of balance, whereas « à part » and « hormis » both permit identifying the exception prior to making reference to the whole group in a less awkward and more balanced way.

Therefore, to me all three seem to be interchangeable EXCEPT for when « à part » and « hormis » begin a sentence, in which case it would be best to invert the word order if one wanted to replace either of them with « autre(s) que »:

> A part les pommes, j’adore les fruits.
>
> Hormis les pommes, j’adore les fruits.
>
> J’adore les fruits, autres que les pommes.